# AngularJS service return status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing custom `$http` service that look something like this:

```
angular.factory('myHttp', function($http){
  var obj = {};

  obj.get = function(path) {
     return $http.get(path).then(function(result){
        return result;
     },function(result){
       console.log("result error:"+path);
       return result;
   });
 }
```

Then, the service can be used like this:

```
    myHttp.get($scope.url).
      then(function(response) {
        console.log("It's success");
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.data = response.data;
      }, function(response) {
        console.log("It's fail");
        $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = response.status;
    });
```

It does return the result on both success and fail. However, even if it fail, it will still return at the success part. Meaning, if the connection fail, I will still get `It's success` in the console.

How can I make it return on fail section when connection fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [then](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) chaining, which says unless the first then handler methods returns a promise object the second calls success handler will be called.

> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via
>   the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback (unless that
>   value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which
>   is resolved in that promise using promise chaining). It also notifies
>   via the return value of the notifyCallback method. The promise cannot
>   be resolved or rejected from the notifyCallback method.

Since in your case you are returning the `result` object from the first handler, the promise returned by the `then` method is considered as resolved so the success handler of the second `then` is invoked.

You can use the success/error handlers as below to fix it

```
obj.get = function (path) {
    return $http.get(path).error(function (result) {
        console.log("result error:" + path);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Your solution works for returning the error. However, if I want it to retry the fail connection for several times before output as fail, how can it be done? It seems like doesn't work with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have written two way to get mehtod calling and handle error

**1. $http functions  already return a Promise object themselves

```
//factory method
obj.get = function (path) {
    return $http.get(path).then(function (results) {
        return results.data;
    });
};

//call from controller
myHttp.get($scope.url).then(function (response) {
    console.log("It's success");
    $scope.status = response.status;
    $scope.data = response.data;
}).error(function (response) {
    console.log("It's fail");
    $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
    $scope.status = response.status;
});


2. The Verbose Way
obj.get = function (path) {
    var def = $q.defer();
    $http.get(path).success(function (data) {
        def.resolve(data);
    }).error(function () {
        def.reject("Failed to get");
    });
    return def.promise;
};

//call from controller
myHttp.get($scope.url).then(function (response) {
    console.log("It's success");
    $scope.status = response.status;
    $scope.data = response.data;
},
function (response) {
    console.log("It's fail");
    $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
    $scope.status = response.status;
});
```

Here is the link for clear understanding [$http](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Oct/24/AngularJs-and-Promises-with-the-http-Service#TheVerboseWay)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your factory method does not capture the fail connection. Meaning I want both success and fail to go through factory to do some processing before passing back to controller.

Comment: use The Verbose Way or apply .error(function (response) method into factory

Comment: Tried with your verbose way. It works, but either success or fail, no data pass over.